# how to add double quotation around variable name in query ?

Tags: android, sqlite

How do I add quotation around string variable any idea? my database execute query if `""` is around variable name what do I do ? I did this`"+"+ School_name+"+"`but its not working how I add variable name with quotation ?

```
       Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        School_name = bundle.getString("Serachvalue");



             db.selectQuery("SELECT * FROM uss_school sch LEFT JOIN uss_school_to_level sl ON  
    sch.school_id = sl.school_id LEFT JOIN uss_level l ON sl.level_id = l.level_id WHERE  
   l.title  ="+ School_name+" ORDER BY sch.name ASC");
```

But data base execute wuery with in quotes,

```
         SELECT * FROM uss_school sch LEFT JOIN uss_school_to_level sl ON sch.school_id =  
                  sl.school_id LEFT JOIN uss_level l ON sl.level_id
= l.level_id WHERE l.title = "Elementary" ORDER BY sch.name ASC
```

Comment: user escape characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following way,

```
db.selectQuery("SELECT * FROM uss_school sch LEFT JOIN uss_school_to_level sl ON  
    sch.school_id = sl.school_id LEFT JOIN uss_level l ON sl.level_id = l.level_id WHERE  
   l.title  ='"+ School_name+"' ORDER BY sch.name ASC");
```

You simply need to add `'` whenever you are using string variable in query field.